# Regex match each line

Tags: regex

I have a whole bunch of strings which I need to clean

```
    35653_3100552_26952012_cmp.xml.gz
    35653_3100552_26952012_cmp_delta.xml.gz
    35653_3100552_26952012_cmp_deltatemplate.txt.gz
    35653_3100552_26952012_cmp_template.txt.gz
    35653_3100552_26952030_cmp.xml.gz
    35653_3100552_26952030_cmp_delta.xml.gz
    35653_3100552_26952030_cmp_deltatemplate.txt.gz
    35653_3100552_26952030_cmp_template.txt.gz
    35653_3100552_26952044_cmp.xml.gz
    35653_3100552_26952044_cmp_delta.xml.gz
    35653_3100552_26952044_cmp_deltatemplate.txt.gz
    35653_3100552_26952044_cmp_template.txt.gz
    35653_3100552_26952063_cmp.xml.gz
    35653_3100552_26952063_cmp_delta.xml.gz
    35653_3100552_26952063_cmp_deltatemplate.txt.gz
    35653_3100552_26952063_cmp_template.txt.gz
    35653_3100552_26952075_cmp.xml.gz
    35653_3100552_26952075_cmp_delta.xml.gz
    35653_3100552_26952075_cmp_deltatemplate.txt.gz
    35653_3100552_26952075_cmp_template.txt.gz
    35653_3100552_26952086_cmp.xml.gz
    35653_3100552_26952086_cmp_delta.xml.gz
    35653_3100552_26952086_cmp_deltatemplate.txt.gz
    35653_3100552_26952086_cmp_template.txt.gz
    35653_3100552_26952105_cmp.xml.gz
    35653_3100552_26952105_cmp_delta.xml.gz
    35653_3100552_26952105_cmp_deltatemplate.txt.gz
    35653_3100552_26952105_cmp_template.txt.gz
```

I just want to keep the ones ending with `cmp.xml.gz`
Everything else I want to remove as well as removing the empty spaces.

I tried this `35653(.*)cmp_delta.xml.gz` but this just selects everything from the 2nd row all the way to the last row.

So my question is, which regex can I use to remove every line which does not end with `cmp_delta.xml.gz`?

Btw, I'm going to be using this regex inside Coda.

Thanks

**Update**

Having tried the regex provided by Kendall and Key in the answers below, this is the result in Coda

```
    35653_3100552_26952012_cmp.xml.gz.lmp
    .lmp
    35653_3100552_26952012_cmp_deltatemplate.txt.gz.lmp
    35653_3100552_26952012_cmp_template.txt.gz.lmp
    35653_3100552_26952030_cmp.xml.gz.lmp
    .lmp
    35653_3100552_26952030_cmp_deltatemplate.txt.gz.lmp
    35653_3100552_26952030_cmp_template.txt.gz.lmp
    35653_3100552_26952044_cmp.xml.gz.lmp
    .lmp
    35653_3100552_26952044_cmp_deltatemplate.txt.gz.lmp
    35653_3100552_26952044_cmp_template.txt.gz.lmp
    35653_3100552_26952063_cmp.xml.gz.lmp
    .lmp
    35653_3100552_26952063_cmp_deltatemplate.txt.gz.lmp
    35653_3100552_26952063_cmp_template.txt.gz.lmp
    35653_3100552_26952075_cmp.xml.gz.lmp
    .lmp
    35653_3100552_26952075_cmp_deltatemplate.txt.gz.lmp
    35653_3100552_26952075_cmp_template.txt.gz.lmp
    35653_3100552_26952086_cmp.xml.gz.lmp
    .lmp
    35653_3100552_26952086_cmp_deltatemplate.txt.gz.lmp
    35653_3100552_26952086_cmp_template.txt.gz.lmp
    35653_3100552_26952105_cmp.xml.gz.lmp
    .lmp
    35653_3100552_26952105_cmp_deltatemplate.txt.gz.lmp
    35653_3100552_26952105_cmp_template.txt.gz.lmp
```

Comment: What syntax do you use: .NET regex, Perl regex, etc.?

Comment:  The title of this question is very general and should be more specific. 7k visit without any vote proves it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That regex will not match more than one line in the default mode, as `.` does not match a newline. The only way it will match is if the regex is in "single-line" mode, which just means that `.` *does* match newlines.

If Coda allows you to, turn off single-line mode (this is not the same as turning on multi-line mode; a regex can be using both modes, or neither).

If Coda doesn't provide an option to change the single-line flag, you can emulate `.` with `[^\r\n]`.

```
35653[^\r\n]*cmp_delta\.xml\.gz
```

Update:

If you can use multiline mode in Coda, turn that on, and add a `$` to the end of the regex.

If not, you might find success if you add `(?=[\r\n])` to the end. I don't know what Coda supports, so I can't say for sure what will work.

Although, if every line ends with `.lmp`, just adding `\.lmp` to the end of the regex makes more sense.

Update:

It appears that the best solution in Coda is to replace all lines not ending with `cmp_delta.xml.gz.lmp` with an empty string.

```
35653[^\r\n]*(?=[\r\n])(?<!cmp_delta\.xml\.gz\.lmp)
```

Comment: I've updated the question with the results using the above regex

Comment: I can't find on google any mention of multiline mode for coda. You said add (?=[\r\n]) to the end, sorry for the noob question but add to the end of where?

Comment: How about another way, I've managed to use find and replace to remove all of the other ending elements. Is it possible to have regex to match everything except lines ending with 'cmp.xml.gz.lmp'

Comment: @user2028856 That would go at the end of the regex. It's also possible to only match lines that don't end with that string, but it has poor support in regex engines, and there's a good chance Coda doesn't support it.

Comment: I'm a total noob with regex so can I ask you to please at least let me have a try with the regex matching lines that don't end with that string?

Comment: `35653[^\r\n]*(?=[\r\n])(?<!cmp_delta\.xml\.gz\.lmp)` would be the syntax for matching lines that don't end in `cmp_delta.xml.gz.lmp`

Comment: OMG you're a GOD. That totally worked! Can you please set that as the answer and I'll accept it? Thanks !!!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
35653(.*?)cmp_delta.xml.gz
```

Instead of your

```
35653(.*)cmp_delta.xml.gz
```

The extra '?' makes the '*' act not-greedy, that's to say it will match the smallest amount of characters possible.

In other terms, when you use `35653(.*)cmp_delta.xml.gz` you are matching "35653" on the first occurrence and the last occurrence of "cmp_delta.xml.gz" of the whole sequence.

Instead `35653(.*?)cmp_delta.xml.gz` will match "35653" on the first occurrence and up to the first occurrence of "cmp_delta.xml.gz".

Answer (score 0):

Do a find and replace. Find `^.*(?<!cmp\.xml\.gz)$\n?` and replace with nothing.

Comment: No, it just deletes the lines not ending with "cmp.xml.gz".

Comment: I've just tried this and unfortunately it does remove everything

Comment: I guess somewhere the “dot matches all” option (`s` modifier) is enabled then. It should be disabled for my regex.